# «Грамота»: вопрос 311361

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие, двоеточие-тире

Почему в этом вопросе «Грамота» ставит тире? Почему не предлагает варианты с двоеточием?

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие знаки препинания необходимы в данном предложении? Они живут везде и на суше и в воде!
>
> ---
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> ---
>
> Корректно: *Они живут везде — и на суше, и в воде!*

Мне кажется, и двоеточие возможно:

*Они живут везде: и на суше, и в воде!*

*Везде* — обобщающее слово, *на суше, в воде* — однородные члены, обобщаемые словом *везде*.

Так почему «Грамота» предлагает вариант именно с тире, почему двоеточия не упоминает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грамота, вероятно, предполагает такую ситуацию:

*— Они где живут, **на суше или в воде**?*

*— Они живут **везде** — и на суше, и в воде.*

Значимым является **обобщающее слово**, однородный ряд присоединяется (он повторяется).

Сравнить: *Они адаптировались к внешней среде и живут везде: **и на суше, и в воде.***

Значимым является **однородный ряд.**